# using tapply() with strptime() formatted date

Tags: r, strptime, tapply

I just want to calculate a daily mean from a set of values taken periodically throughout the day, but for a number of different days in a data set. tapply() is great, when my date is a factor

```
    > Data$Data <- as.factor(Data$Date)
    > str(Data$Date)
    Factor w/ 55 levels "01/05/2014","02/05/2014",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
    > tapply(Data$Humidity,Data$Date, FUN = mean)
    01/05/2014 02/05/2014 03/04/2014 03/05/2014 04/04/2014 04/05/2014 05/04/2014 05/05/2014 06/04/2014 
    99.96875   100.00000  96.65833   99.80625   84.14375   89.56042   93.75833   39.58750   87.55000
```

This gives me exactly what I want but these dates are no longer in chronological order as I have done it as a factor.

Instead I have tried using strptime() as a recognised date format by R. Starting again from the beginning....

```
    > Data$Date<-strptime(Data$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
    > str(Data$Date)
    POSIXlt[1:2586], format: "2014-04-03" "2014-04-03" "2014-04-03" "2014-04-03" "2014-04-03" "2014-04-03" ...
    > tapply(Data$Humidity,Data$Date, FUN = mean)
    Error in INDEX[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

But I just get the following error message? Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found that I can simply alter the tapply() output to strptime() afterwards, via a dataframe() rather than trying to do it before, then order() by date

```
    Data$Date <- as.factor(Data$Date)
    DAVEH <- tapply(Data$Humidity,Data$Date, FUN = mean)

    site.daily<-data.frame(c(names(DAVEH)),c(DAVEH))
    rownames(site.daily)<-seq_len(nrow(site.daily))
    colnames(site.daily)<-c("Date","DAVEH")

    site.daily$Date<-strptime(site.daily$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

    site.daily<-site.daily[order(site.daily$Date),]
    rownames(site.daily)<-seq_len(nrow(site.daily)) # again as they have been re-ordered

  > site.daily
     Date     DAVEH
 1  2014-04-03  96.65833
 2  2014-04-04  84.14375
 3  2014-04-05  93.75833
 4  2014-04-06  87.55000
 5  2014-04-07  58.87708
 6  2014-04-08  99.83542
 7  2014-04-09  87.68125.....
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at a package like dplyr that doesn't need a factor like the tapply function. => http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf

Syntax would be like,

```
DF <- your data frame
gb <- group_by(DF, Date)
DF <- mutate(gb, Mean_Humidity = mean(Humidity)
DF <- arrange(DF, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert your Date to a factor when you do the `tapply`

```
tapply(Data$Humidity,factor(Data$Date), FUN = mean)
```

The `tapply` function requires a factor.